# Returning mongoose result to a variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I know this is a basic question but i can't figure it out. I tried something with callback for asynchronous functions but its not solving my problem. So here is my code.

```
Collection1.find({archived:false}).exec().then(obj => {

obj = _.groupBy(obj,'department');
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {

  const object_collection =[];

  function retrieveUser(callback) {
    for(let i = 0;i obj[key].length; i++){

      French.find(function(err, users) {
        if (err) {
          callback(err, null);
        } else {
          callback(null, users[0]);
        }
      });

    };
  };

  retrieveUser(function(err, user) {
    object_collection.push(user);
  });

  // i need object_collection here after for loop has done
  console.log(object_collection);


});

})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I can do with the provided details.

If you're using Node.js v7.6 or above, you can leverage `async/await` usage and make this easier for you, refactoring as follows.

```
async function yourFunctionName(req, res) {
    const obj = await Collection1.find({archived:false}).exec();

    obj = _.groupBy(obj, 'department');

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        const object_collection = [];
        const frenchPromises = [];

        for (let i= 0; i <= obj[key].length; i ++) {
            // This will create an array of promises that will be resolved later.
            frenchPromises.push(
                // This will do the same as your callback, but returning a promise.
                French.find().exec().then(users => users[0])
            );
        }

        // When awaiting a Promise.all we will get an array containing the results
        // of all the promises insde the frenchPromises array.
        // Meaning, that we will get back the array of users from the previous code.
        object_collection = await Promise.all(frenchPromises);

        console.log(object_collection)
    });
}
```

If not leveraging `async/await` here's the same but with just Promises.

```
const obj = Collection1.find({ archived: false })
    .exec()
    .then(obj => {
        obj = _.groupBy(obj, 'department');
        const frenchPromises = [];

        Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
            for (let i = 0; i <= obj[key].length; i++) {
                // This will create an array of promises that will be resolved later.
                frenchPromises.push(
                    // This will do the same as your callback, but returning a promise.
                    French.find().exec().then(users => users[0])
                );
            }
        });

        // Returns an array of promises that will be resolved in the next .then() call
        return Promise.all(frenchPromises);
    }) // This will return the array of users
    .then(object_collection => {
        console.log(object_collection);
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your effort on this. I have solved my problem with a way similar to this.Ive assigned ‘async function’ after ‘foreach’ only for ‘for loop’ and pushed returned value to array. But i’ll keep this way on my mind !